# Authorizing facebook connect users with other third parties

Tags: api, authentication, facebook

I'm working on a site that has a large proportion of users signing in via Facebook Connect, so they don't have a username and password for our site. We offer our own user-authenticated API  using basic auth, but this doesn't allow facebook connect users to authenticate with clients using our API.

Is there any way that doesn't break Facebook's TOS to authorize other third parties using Facebook authentication credentials? For instance, if the other site implements facebook connect and passes session data back to us? Are there any examples in the wild of facebook connect being used successfully by an API provider other than sites like Foursquare that use oAuth as a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I have developed such a feature for my application. User can sign in with Facebook or Twitter on our web front, and they can also authenticate themselves the same way on our API from iPhone/Android app.

I am not sure my method is the best one, that's why I [asked the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817991/facebook-connect-to-authenticate-on-a-personal-api) about what could be the best approach. Still, I'm going to explain what I'm doing and so far this is working very well.

First, you need to implement a `login` method in your API. This method exchanges your credentials against an API token which will then used for all the future calls.

Here is the `login` API call with your basic authentication parameters:

```
http://login:password@api.myapp.com/login
```

(this is just a representation to explain you are sending the credentials, not the actual way to do it)

In return, this API call sends you the `api_token`

```
{ "api_token": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" }
```

Server side, you have a table associating `api_token` and `user_id` (as well as expiration date if needed, etc.)

You'll then use `api_token` each time you need to make an authenticated call:

```
http://api.myapp.com/request?api_token=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

Now that you have modified your authentication implementation, you will do exactly the same with the Facebook `access_token` sent back by the Facebook Connect SDK. You exchange tokens using the following API call:

```
http://api.myapp.com/login/facebook?access_token=<facebook_access_token>
```

Server side, you verify validity of the `access_token` with a simple

```
wget -qO- https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<facebook_access_token>
```

Which sends you back a JSON with all user information, including user's Facebook ID. Assuming the user has already connected his account to Facebook, you can lookup the `user_id` and send back an `api_token`.

Problem is that if user rejects your application from Facebook, this won't have any effect on the `api_token` and user will still have access to the API. There could be also some security issues (https would certainly be better to protect user's facebook access token).

I can't vouch for the beauty of this method, but it works and can be used with many other vendors. As the Facebook access token is staying in the same ecosystem, I'm pretty sure this doesn't violate Facebook's TOS. I have read nothing there looking against it.