# Facebook Connect to authenticate on a personal API

Tags: api, authentication, facebook

I have developed a simple API to allow communication between my Android/iPhone apps and my server. In my application, users need to authenticate themselves and they do it using login/password credentials with the following API call:

```
http://api.myapp.com/login?user=xxx&pass=pass
```

Application receives in return:

```
{ "api_token": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" }
```

So basically I exchange my credentials against `api_token`.

I would like to add Facebook connect support. I have successfully used the Facebook SDK and receives the correct `access_token`.

However, I need to implement a mechanism to exchange `access_token` with `api_token`

Assuming the user has already connected his account with Facebook (on his web user panel), what would be the best implementation to proceed to the exchange?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I finally did it. It's working very well for more than one year, never had any problem. The idea is to exchange tokens using the following API call:

```
http://api.myapp.com/login/facebook?access_token=<facebook_access_token>
```

Server side, you verify validity of the `access_token` with a simple

```
wget -qO- https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<facebook_access_token>
```

Which sends you back a JSON with all user information, including user's Facebook ID. Assuming the user has already connected his account to Facebook, you can lookup the `user_id` and send back an `api_token`.

Comment: Here's the scenario that I'm concerned about:

App A acquires a fb access token for user with permissions X.
App A visits your login url at `http://api.myapp.com/login/facebook?access_token=...`

Since you now have the access token that app A has acquired, you now have all of the same access to the user as they did, without the user having given you permission to do so (they've only granted permission to app A).  While I can see this as defensible in a number of ways, it still seems somewhat wrong, and potentially a violation of user's trust.

What do you think?

Comment: Well in a way yes you are right, but as far as I'm concerned, we are "App A". IMHO, it's the same as a user subscribing to our newsletter: we could spam the user or sell the email to tons of third parties but we aren't because we are a responsible company (with liability to the law)

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

The best implementation will naturally depend upon your current platform.  There are several Ruby on Rails gems, for example, that handle to whole Open Authentication bit for you.