# Facebook authentication for JSON service with android application

Tags: android, web-services, security, facebook-access-token, facebook-android-sdk

I'm writing an android app that uses a JSON web service and I'd like to use Facebook for the authentication.

What I'm not sure about is how to secure the web service.

Should I use the authentication token returned from the Facebook login as the password to the web service?

I'm not sure on where the token is stored and how to retrieve it? Also how could I update the web service with the new token when it expires?

I'm considering just using an api key but that would mean someone could abuse the web service if they decompiled the apk and got the api key out.

Any suggestions are welcome.

I'm using PhoneGap so I guess there is the option of using cookies but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: Two questions:  Are you creating a user account on your own backend once a Facebook auth has been successful?  And are you wanting to know how to secure access to the backend from the new user account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches been discussed here at Stack Overflow

> 1> [How do I authenticate with my own site's API when using Facebook Connect for logins/account creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949825/how-do-i-authenticate-with-my-own-sites-api-when-using-facebook-connect-for-log)
>
> 2> [Facebook Connect to authenticate on a personal API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817991/facebook-connect-to-authenticate-on-a-personal-api)

See if they work for you.

Comment: Thanks, the answer in the second link sounds like a feasible solution. I was looking for a way to not have to validate the authtoken on the server but I don't think there is one. Plus it looks quite easy as it is a simple http request.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use the authentication token returned from the Facebook login as the password to the web service?

I recommend using one of our supported SDK's to handle the login auth.  You, as the developer, does not have to worry about storing passwords/tokens/etc.  By using fb login, we handle all of that.  I recommend reading more about using Facebook as a login [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/).

> I'm not sure on where the token is stored and how to retrieve it? Also how could I update the web service with the new token when it expires?

I would recommend reading [this doc](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) to see how we recommend to retrieve and update access token when it expires.

Comment: I'm already using the Facebook login but that is to secure the app rather than the web service. My concern is protecting the web service from unauthorised use.