# How do I authenticate with my own site's API when using Facebook Connect for logins/account creation?

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, facebook

The title speaks to the majority of the question, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around how I have Facebook authenticated users gain access to my own site's API.

After the user has authenticated with FB I have a little bit of information available about the user, but no API key or username/password to pass along to my own secure API server for authentication.

I've found several related questions, but nothing that seems like an ideal answers:

- [Facebook Connect to authenticate on a personal API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817991/facebook-connect-to-authenticate-on-a-personal-api)
- [Authorizing facebook connect users with other third parties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859904/authorizing-facebook-connect-users-with-other-third-parties)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say 'your own sites API' do you mean authenticating calls between a browser and your website, or do you mean your own api that anything/anyone can consume, such as 3rd parties and mobile devices?

Comment: @spotman - Thanks for actually being helpful instead of just being a dick. My site uses my own API to get content rather than a database connection. I'm authenticating them on the web side with FB Connect, but I'm hunting for the best method to then turn around and authenticate them with my own API. Was doing Basic Auth, but FB Connect users don't have passwords to authenticate with. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are authenticating your users through Facebook connect, you know enough about the user.

Regardless of the [authentication flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) you are using, you'll

**STEP #1:** receive an `access_token` and a `expire` parameter. Most likely, you've requested the `user_id` too (if you are using the JS-SDK it would handle most of this).

**STEP #2:** encapsulate these info (`access_token`, `expire` & `user_id`) in a hashed string, e.g. *mimic* the Facebook [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) format.

**STEP #3:** send this hashed string in your own API calls:

```
https://mydomain.com/apis/getUserSecretData?fb_oauth=my_hashed_string&vars=my_other_vars
```

**STEP #4:** in your API end-point, decrypt/decode your hashed string and verify the `expire` parameter and if the `access_token` is expired, then you need to request a new one and repeat your API call.

Comment: I really like this! Thanks for being so helpful. One follow-up question: After Step #4 is it safe to have my API endpoint return an API key to the client which it can use for the rest of it's requests or should I just put all my requests into a signed_request?

Comment: The problem is if a malicious user decompiles your app and gets the key used to sign the request then they can use any auth token with an arbitrary userid because you are not validating the userid against the authtoken. This is more of an issue when the application is a mobile app because it is easy to decompile. For a web app it isn't so important because your encryption key would be stored on the Web server securely. This question shows how to validate the userid against the authtoken from the api http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817991/facebook-connect-to-authenticate-on-a-personal-api